# Computing a mean value every x ms

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a stream that emits some data.

```
const data$ = Rx
  .Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map(() => Math.random() * 100)
```

And I would like to compute a mean value for all produced values over a period of time (every second for example)

If the `data$` stream emits `-2-2-2-4|`, I'd like the resulting stream to be `---2---3|`

How would you do that with `rxjs` (version 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bufferTime` is a way to go:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map(() => Math.random() * 100)
  .do(console.log)
  .bufferTime(2000)
  .map(items => {
    return items.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) / items.length;
  })
  .take(3)
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log('mean: ' + val);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.1/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Ok, Maxime's point is valid. If you need to calculate mean of great number of values consider using `windowTime`:

```js
var interval = Rx.Observable.interval(2000);

Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map(() => Math.random() * 100)
  .do(console.log)
  .window(interval)
  .map(win => {
    return win.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      acc.count++;
      acc.sum += cur;
      return acc;
    }, {
      count: 0,
      sum: 0,
    });
  })
  .mergeAll()
  .filter(val => val.count != 0)
  .map(val => val.sum / val.count)
  .take(3)
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log('mean: ' + val);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.1/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh cool, thanks Sergey, that's is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Sergey Sokolov's answer might be ok if indeed you need to catch a value every second. But let say for example that it'd rather be every hour, the `bufferTime` would potentially have to keep in memory the values during that time. And here, if I understand your problem, you do not need to keep those values.

So it might be a better idea to do something like that:

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const tick$ = Observable.interval(2000);

const myObs$ = Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map(() => Math.random() * 100)
  .do(x => console.log(`Emit ${x}`));

const finalObs$ = tick$
  .withLatestFrom(myObs$)
  .map(([_, val]) => val)
  .do(x => console.warn(`Taken ${x}`));

// only to test
finalObs$.take(3).subscribe();
```

Output:

[image]

And every `console.log` here is just to debug but in your final observable you'll only have value in yellow from the above screen capture.

Here's a working Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/sR4Dg1gD3Zh2yWUtl0RI?p=preview

Comment: But you are only taking the last value, which is not what I want (I want the mean value). Sergey updated his answer taking your remark into account :)

Comment: Ok I misunderstood, then you should go with his answer for sure ;)